# Extend a homomorphism $\mathrm{PSL}(2,3) \to \mathrm{PGL}(n, \mathbb{C})$ to a homomorphism $\mathrm{SL}(2,3) \to \mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, projective-space

(Here by $\mathrm{SL}(2,3)$, I am referring to $2 \times 2$ matrices of determinant $1$ over the field of order $3$, and by $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{C})$, I am referring to $n \times n$ nonsingular matrices over the complex numbers. The $\mathrm{P}$ prefix refers to quotienting one of these groups by its center, the subgroup of scalar matrices.)

In learning about projective representations and Schur multipliers in group theory, I am attempting to prove that $\mathrm{SL}(2,3)$ is a cover of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,3)$. The last step is to show that the “projective lifting property” holds:

> Let $v \colon \mathrm{SL}(2,3) \to \mathrm{PSL}(2,3)$ and $\pi \colon \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C}) \to \mathrm{PGL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ be the quotient maps. Then, for any homomorphism $\tau \colon \mathrm{PSL}(2,3) \to \mathrm{PGL}(n,\mathbb{C})$, there exists a homomorphism $\overline{\tau} \colon \mathrm{SL}(2,3) \to \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ such that $\pi \overline{\tau} = \tau v$.
> $$
>   \require{AMScd}
>   \begin{CD}
>     \mathrm{SL}(2, 3)
>     @>{\overline{\tau}}>>
>     \mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{C})
>     \\
>     @V{v}VV  @VV{\pi}V
>     \\
>     \mathrm{PSL}(2, 3)
>     @>>{\tau}>
>     \mathrm{PGL}(n, \mathbb{C})
>   \end{CD}
> $$

From the existence of a cover, we would then be able to immediately conclude what the Schur multiplier of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,3)$ is: it is isomorphic to the subgroup of scalar matrices of $\mathrm{SL}(2,3)$, which is in turn isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

I am looking for a proof (using methods that a reader of Rotman’s *An Introduction to the Theory of Groups* can follow) that the highlighted “projective lifting property” above holds.

Comment: I would do this the other way round, that is show first that $M({\rm PSL}(2,3)) \cong C_2$, which implies that ${\rm SL}(2,3)$ is a cover of ${\rm PSL}(2,3)$, from which the projective property follows. Since ${\rm PSL}(2,3) \cong A_4$, this is actually Exercise 11.22 (iii) in Rotman's book, which is similar to the example in Corollary 11.23.